# Find out if X509Certificate2 is revoked?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I figure out if an `X509Certificate2` has been revoked?
I assume the `Verify()` method checks it, but it doesn't explicitly state it in the help. 
Does anybody know?

Also: does the Verify() check if the certificate is expired?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried using the [X509Chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.aspx)?

```
var chain = new X509Chain();
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;
chain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(1000);
chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime = DateTime.Now;
var elementValid = chain.Build (x509certificate);
```

Comment: I will. Still I'm unclear what the Verify() is doing? Why is it not documented?

Comment: Teh documentation for Verify says: "Performs a X.509 chain validation using basic validation policy". You can specify your own validation policy by setting the ChainPolicy when verifying using X509Chain.

Comment: Yeah, but what IS a "basic validation policy"? Does it include revocation check or not, for instance?

Comment: I would say the default settings of the X509Chain.ChainPolicy

Comment: Can you please give details on `X509RevocationMode.Online;` Does it required internet connectivity?

Comment: Shouldn't `Build()` be called **after** the chain policy setup?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.build.aspx

Comment: I think it would be better to rely instead on the `boolean` returned by the `Build()` method when validating the whole chain. This way, you can even customize the validation with the `X509ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags` property as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2011/06/21/how-to-verify-validity-of-certificates-with-net.aspx) (it's illustrated for VB but it's equally valid for C# as well).

Comment: @GabrielS.'s link is dead, https://web.archive.org/web/20150214092703/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2011/06/21/how-to-verify-validity-of-certificates-with-net.aspx